# Building json strings in Python - issues with strings and unicode

Tags: python, json

Cannot get variable type into format with inverted commas. Basically I extract some info from a json dictionary (an API) and then I want to build my own json with it but I'm having problems with types. Basically what I extract from the jason is unicode (checked with type(extract)) and I want to create a string as:

```
myjson = '"extract":' + str(extract)
```

However always when I print out myjson, I don't get the extract in strings or quotes which causes problems later on when passing the json. Now this seems to work for some values which are extracted from the API but not others. How can I ensure that the built strings are always properly formatted? I.e. loading the myjson doesn't break. So when I print out, I get `"extract": xyz 123`, but the `xyz 123` is *not* `"xyz 123"`

I've also converted from unicode to string type by using:

```
encode('ascii','ignore')
```

i.e:

```
myjson = '"extract":' + str(extract.encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

Why is a bullet proof way to build up the json strings with this issue?

Comment: Why build a string?  If you are working with JSON input, can you stay working with dicts instead?  have you looked at json.loads and json.dumps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
myjson = json.dumps({
    "extract": extract
})
```